# Coupon Collector's problem, characteristic function and Gumbel distribution

Tags: probability

Can anyone help me with computing the characteristic function for the coupon collector's problem:

Let $(X_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ be iid random variables uniformly distributed on {1,2,3,..,N}. Let $T_N$ be the smallest index $n$ such that {1,...,N}$\subset${$X_1$,...,$X_n$} , ie the least number of trials such that all the N coupons have been obtained. Use characteristic functions to show that ${{T_N-N\log{N}}\over N}$ converges to the Gumbel distribution.

I have searched for articles online and their methods do not involve characteristic functions. I have computed the characteristic function for Gumbel distribution: $\Gamma(1-it)$, where $i$ is the imaginary number.

Can someone out there kindly help me? Thank you.

Comment: You searched for the literature, good--but what did you try yourself to solve the problem? You even have been given a hint...

Comment: I face the difficulty of evaluating the characteristic function of ${{T_N-NlogN} \over N}$ as I require the probability density function of this random variable to evaluate the integral.

Comment: The PDF is not needed since, if $\varphi(t)=E[e^{itX}]$ and $Y=aX+b$ then $E[e^{itY}]=e^{itb}\varphi(at)$.

Comment: Oh ya. The linear transformation of characteristic functions! But if that's the case, then one ought to know the PDF of $T_N$.

Comment: Not necessarily. One can stay at the level of characteristic functions. By the way, did you write down the CF of $T_N$?

Comment: Hi. I got some feedback from my lecturer regarding this question. He suggested transforming $T_N$ into $X_1+X_2+...+X_N$, where $X_i$ follows a geometric distribution of parameter ${{N-i+1}\over N}$. Then we can calculate the characteristic function of individual $X_i$s, take their product and do the translation. How do you think about this method?

Comment: That it is clearly delineated by your teacher and that now, you just have to follow it step by step.

Comment: I was wondering whether you have alternate methods. Normally to compute characteristic functions, we need to have the PDF of the random variable, which sometimes will be difficult to obtain. I mean, it may not be so clear cut to identify the PDF of the random variable at first glance.

Comment: Can't compute the CF of a geometric distribution? C'mon!